# installing mtpro2 latex font on server based TeXLive 2013 distribution?

Tags: fonts, texlive, mtpro

I am trying to get the `mtpro2` latex fonts installed on our linux server, which hosts `TexLive 2013`. From the client machines the users can then call the respective compilation commands however needed. I cannot seem to figure out how to get the fonts installed though. Wouldn't they be installed locally only? Do they need to be available on the server and client machines? Has anyone tried to accomplish this?

Comment: Installing the package's components in LOCALTEXMF should work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: but `LOCALTEXMF` on the server is not accessible by the client right? So you'd suggest installing it into the clients `LOCALTEXMF`?

Comment: Sorry, I exchanged the order of the two parts of the word: I meant to write **TEXMFLOCAL**. According to the TeXLive user guide, TEXMFLOCAL is the "tree which administrators can use for *system-wide installation of additional or updated macros, fonts*, etc" [emphasis added]. (You may be thinking of TEXMFHOME, which according to the user guide is the "tree which users can use for their own individual installations of additional or updated macros, fonts, etc.")

Comment: Thanks for the reply! when checking what `TEXMFLOCAL` on the server points to, I get `/usr/local/share/texmf` which would be local only right?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with how TeXLive is installed on Linux machines, so I can't tell if the folder that points to TEXMFLOCAL is visible to all users or not. :-( Maybe someone with Linux experience can jump in?

Comment: Unless you do something weird (or somebody else does) /usr/local/share/texmf will be visible to all users with standard access to the machine. That is not the default value of TEXMFLOCAL in TeX Live, though. Usually it is /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local.